# tinymce Link & Image buttons issue

Tags: tinymce-4

I've install TinyMCE v4.1.9 text editor. so I found hyperlink and Image buttons ara missing, so I insert the plugins for both of them and they both appear but, they just appear only if I add one plugin (when I add Image --> appear | when I add hyperlink --> appear | when I add both, when the hyperlink is the last, link button appear and image disappear and if the image is the last, same thing, the image button appear and link disappear).

here are my codes:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#core",
        language : 'ar',
        directionality : 'rtl',
        plugins: "autoresize",
        fontsize_formats: "14px",
        content_css : "css/custom_content.min.css",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values : "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        plugins: "link",
        plugins: "image",
        theme: 'modern'
```

help please

Answer (score 0):

**this is the right answer**

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#core",
    theme: "modern",
    language : 'ar',
    directionality : 'rtl',
    plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: It would also be good to add a small description of your solution.

Comment: thank you bro but I did solved it a long time ago :) thanks for sharing, appreciate it ^_^